# Can I assume an HDMI female to micro-HDMI male adapter is bidirectional?

Tags: hdmi, adapter, connector

I'm looking at this adapter:

[image]

which is advertized as HDMI to mini-HDMI. Well - can I assume it'll work the other way around, i.e. adapting a mini-HDMI output port for a full-HDMI cable?

Answer (score 0):

its essentially HDMI to HDMI, merely a form factor conversion, bidirectional is a given; having said that the adapter or the cable may be flawed or be at fault to.

Comment: I haven't bought it yet... I'm just wondering whether this could be an issue.